# My wordpress sub-menu splits in two column, how to stack them in one column

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, frontend, wordpress-theming

[image]

As you guys can see, my WordPress submenu automatically splits into two columns, but I want to stack my submenu in one column. I tried various methods of implementing CSS but none of them give satisfactory results. If anyone has an idea... please let me know how to make this possible

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a flex CSS on the parent element with flex-direction: column; and see how it goes. Otherwise, I would suggest to check if there are any settings for that menu inside your WordPress Themes customization page.